# How do I move a block of code in a method for "efficiency" purposes?

Tags: iphone

I think I have a conceptual misunderstanding and would appreciate an explanation.

Within a class, I had the same block of code repeating 3 times (and working perfectly) but to try to make things more "efficient" I took it out and made a method within the class as follows:

```
- (void)dateUP {
NSLog(@"dateUp");
[UIView beginAnimations:@"datePicker" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

datePicker.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,-310);
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

and then where the code originally was, I put:

```
[self dateUp];
```

and I put the following in my .h:

```
-(void)dateUp;
```

I build and get this warning:

```
Line Location DetailPopUpView.m:165: warning: method definition for '-dateUp' 
not found
```

and a crash with this in the console (and btw, the NSLog statement doesn't appear in the console):

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '*** -[DetailPopUpView dateUp:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
0x3d33ef0'
```

Any help appreciated.  One thing that I notice is that the console message has dateUp: (with a colon) as if a parameter is expected.  So whereas the simplest solution is just to put the code back, repeating it 3x, I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method is:

```
- (void)dateUP { ... }
```

Your header declaration includes:

```
-(void)dateUp;
```

You might have a spelling error.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  This is embarrassing.  Quite right.  I need more sleep.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have cases where your selectors (method names) aren't matching. `dateUP` is different from `dateUp` which is much different from `dateUp:`

This should work fine:

```
- (void)dateUp
{
    NSLog(@"dateUp");
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"datePicker" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    datePicker.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,-310);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self dateUp];
}
```